# C++ primer class definition (beginner)

Tags: c++

there is this sentence in the book C++ primer before they introduce header files (section 2.6.3 p. 76 fifth edition) :

> When we define a class outside of a function, there may be only one definition of that class in any given source file. In addition, if we use a class in several different files, the class' definition must be the same in each file.

There might be something wrong with the way I interpret the last sentence. My understanding is that if I want to use a class in multiple files of the same project without using headers, I must define that class in each file. The classes in each file all must have the same name and contents or the compiler will complain.

However, I tried to define two classes with the same name but with different contents in two different source files. I even used these classes but it perfectly works.

Comment: In general, _C++ Primer_ classifies undefined behavior as an error like any other, even if the compiler is not required to catch said error: Just because the compiler isn't required to detect an error doesn't make that error less wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, having two different definitions of the same class does not require a diagnostic (i.e., no warning or error message). But the behavior is "undefined", that is, the language definition doesn't tell you what the code is supposed to do. As a result, the code can do anything, including working just fine. Until, of course, you're demonstrating your program for your most important customer, when it will crash.

Comment: Relevant section in the standard: [basic.def.odr] Where D is a class: "If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements,
then the program shall behave as if there were a single definition of D. If the definitions of D do not satisfy
these requirements, then the behavior is undefined." And one of the requirements is basically that the definitions be identical (in that they consist of the same tokens and so on).

Comment: But why is the behavior undefined? I think that different source files without a header have no way of communicating to each other. So source_file1 doesn't know source_file2 have a different class but with the same name, they act like two separate files so they shouldn't conflict with each other...

Comment: @gigi They aren't different classes though. At least, they're not supposed to be. What happens if you pass a pointer to an object of that class to a function defined in the other file? Which class is that pointer supposed to refer to?

Comment: @gigi -- the unsatisfying answer is that it's undefined because the language definition says so. Suppose you have two classes named `X`, each with a member function named `y` that takes no arguments. Traditional linkers can't handle that duplication: there would be two functions with the same name in two different object files, and the linker would either complain or it would pick one for use by the entire program. There's really no good way around that.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't didn't *work perfectly*.  It may have worked but it's Undefined Behaviour to make the definitions different.